# SDL won't work properly in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, sdl-2

I'm trying to get SDL working. I currently have Microsoft Visual Studio installed on my PC, and I am attempting to run this simple code.

```
#include "SDL.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv) {
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```

With this method, I get one singular error message:

```
LNK1561 entry point must be defined
```

Comment: Weird. LNK1561 usually means `main` is missing. Make sure you selected an application project and not a project type that will build a DLL.

Comment: Can you edit in which Windows, Visual Studio, and SDL versions you're using?  Did you grab [the pre-built SDL development binaries](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) or did you build your own?  Are you building your program for 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Visual Studio Express 2017, Windows 10, Windows 'SDL-devel-2.05-VC.zip' Is that helpful?

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv)
                       ^ not quite right...
```

See [the docs](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/1138bf8c009a/include/SDL_main.h#l43) for SDL2's magic `main` macro:

> ```
> /**
>  *  \file SDL_main.h
>  *
>  *  The application's main() function must be called with C linkage,
>  *  and should be declared like this:
>  *  \code
>  *  #ifdef __cplusplus
>  *  extern "C"
>  *  #endif
>  *  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
>  *  {
>  *  }
>  *  \endcode
>  */
>
> #if defined(SDL_MAIN_NEEDED) || defined(SDL_MAIN_AVAILABLE)
> #define main    SDL_main
> #endif
>
> /**
>  *  The prototype for the application's main() function
>  */
> extern C_LINKAGE int SDL_main(int argc, char *argv[]);
> ```

So you want to change to

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Since you're starting from the Empty Project template you might also want to choose a [`/SUBSYSTEM`: usually `CONSOLE` or `WINDOWS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: @EyesightTechnology: Yup, either `main()` should work.

Comment: @EyesightTechnology: You *are* linking against `SDLmain.lib`, right?

Comment: @gempfault: Yes, I have. But I'm VERY new to this, and I may have done it incorrectly. How would you suggest I do the linking? (How do you do it properly?)

Comment: I know it has to do with the properties of the project. But I don't know the specifics.

Comment: @EyesightTechnology: You'll want to add `SDLmain.lib` (and `SDL.lib`) to the "Additional Dependencies" property on [the Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input page](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/msvsnet2010u/additional_dependencies.png) (image from [this tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/msvsnet2010u/index.php)).  The "SubSystem" setting lives on [the System page](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/msvsnet2010u/subsystem.png)

Comment: I added 'SDL2.lib' and 'SDL2main.lib' to Additional Dependencies. I also changed the SYSTEM CONSOLE thing. Is this what you wanted me to do? I now get the following popup 'Unable to start program FILEPATH. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x800700d8'

Comment: @EyesightTechnology: Yup, that sounds right.  Hrm, that's a new error to me.  Do you have a copy of `SDL2.dll` in the Debug/Release directories next to your executable?

Comment: The SDL2.dll file is located in Projects > FirstSDLWIndow (The project name) > FirstSDLWindow. This is the same directory that 'main.cpp' is located. I see another folder labeled 'Debug', which is empty

Comment: @EyesightTechnology: If 'Debug' is empty, where's your executable?

Comment: Good question! How do I... find it... is this a Visual Studio error?

Comment: @EyesightTechnology: I guess I'm assuming your program successfully compiled and linked and you're getting the `0x800700d8` error when trying to run your program.  Is the `0x800700d8` error coming up when you try to compile/link?

Comment: The error appears when I try to run/debug the program. It's in the form of a popup.

Comment: I managed to locate the EXE file. It's in FirstSDLWindow > x64 > Debug, along with 'FirstSDLWindow.ilk' and 'FirstSDLWindow.pdb'. However, when I try to open the EXE, (Just by itself, without Visual Studio) The computer says "This app can't run on your PC.' Could that have something to do with the '0x800700d8' error? How do I get the EXE to open properly?!?!

Comment: @EyesightTechnology: Make sure you copied `SDL2-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip/lib/x64/SDL2.dll` to the directory your executable is in and that you're linking against the 64-bit versions of `SDL2main.lib` and `SDL2.lib`.  That's all I got left troubleshooting-wise, sorry :(

Comment: Figured it out! Needed to select "x86" options when linking, and in the dropdown menu at the top of Visual Studio